# Group Action highly transitive

Tags: group-theory, permutations, group-actions

$\Omega$ is infinite set, $X$ is a primitive permutation group on $\Omega$, then

why if $Alt(\Omega) \leq X$ (that is, $Alt(\Omega)$ is a subgroup of $X$), then $X$ is highly transitive?

Comment: How would you define "highly"?

Comment: @Vim I define highly in this way: 
the action group is highly transitive, if $\Omega$ is a infinite set and $X$ is $k$-transitive for all $k$ integers $k \geq 1$.

Comment: If $\Omega$ is infinite then clearly ${\rm Alt}(\Omega)$ is $k$-transitive on $\Omega$ for any $k \ge 0$, and hence so is $X$.

Comment: Thanks @DerekHolt for the quick reply. 
Sorry if I bother you.
Can you explain why if $\Omega$ is finite, whit cardinality n, then $Alt(\Omega)$ is (n-2)-transitive on $\Omega$?
If I can understand the answer to this question, I can also comprehend your previous answer.

Comment: I really think that you should try and prove that yourself. Can you prove that ${\rm Sym}(\Omega)$ is $n$-transitive?

Comment: Well @DerekHolt  I consider $\Omega^{(n)}$ the set of all n-tuples of distinct points of $\Omega$, now I consider the conjugation action of group $Sym(\Omega)$ on $\Omega^{(n)}$, we know that all elements belonging to the same conjugacy class if they have the same order, therefore all n-tuples belong to the same class, so the action is transitive.
And this is equivalet to saying that $Sym(\Omega)$ is n-transitive on $\Omega$.

Comment: Yes, and in the action of ${\rm Alt}(\Omega)$, you can map the first $n-2$ elements of an $n$-tuple to any other $(n-2)$-tuple, and then you have two choices for the final two elements, one of which gives you an odd permutation and the other an even permutation.

Comment: Thank you very much @DerekHolt for pointing me in the right direction on the topic.